# How to deploy an adf web application that contains j2ee components on tomee?

Tags: oracle-adf, apache-tomee

Firstly, I installed tomcat 7, then i could deploy adf application acc to following url: https://blogs.oracle.com/adfthoughts/entry/running_adf_essentials_in_tomcat
But i want server to run a j2ee application which has model project with jpa and hibernate etc, so i need to TomEE for that. I installed TomEE 1.5.2 version on my win7 system, i applied the same steps that already done for tomcat 7, result is failure.

Plz help me, I am getting following errors:

```
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Cannot unmarshall the JSP tag library definition file: jar:file:/u02/RTE/apache-tomee-plus-1.5.2/webapps/rcf-dvt-demo/WEB-INF/lib/adf-richclient-impl-12-abrams-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/afu.tld: unexpected element (uri:"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", local:"code"). Expected elements are <{^@}text> 
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1903) 
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1073) 
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1033) 
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:124) 
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119) 
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179) 
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) 
        ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is not in ADF, your problem is in the implementation that Tomee is using for EJB (JPA) which is openEJB, see if you configured your EJB Layer correctly?

Comment: Thx 4ur response. The problem was related with an issue that already reported a bug (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-756). i suppose that i change my opinion and prefer glassfish at least until tomee releases are stable